# Layout Problem on Review Page in Mobile Safari

Tags: bug, design

In Mobile Safari (iPad 3, iOS 5.1.1), there is a minor bug on the review page.  Screenshot is from the **First Answers** tab:

[image]

This happens in both portrait and landscape mode.

The equivalent problem does not happen on Stack Overflow:

[image]

so I expect the problem is just with this theme.